# Importing otbApplication in Python?

Tags: python, installation, orfeo-toolbox

I installed both otb-bin and otb-python using OSGeo4W.

In OSGeo4W Shell, I have no problem importing otbApplication.

But I have a problem doing this in Python Shell. The error message is as below:

```
>>> import otbApplication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import otbApplication
ImportError: No module named otbApplication
```

I guess I have to configure some environmental variables, but I have no idea.

My OS is Windows 7 and the Python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220427/import-otbapplication-in-python#comment339157_220427) you appear to be getting this error:

> Because `otbApplication`is not in the PYTHONPATH of QGIS (you can use
>   `import processing.algs.otb`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case was using as Python API (modules). So, I think the solution also applies to QGIS environment!

I'm currently using Linux, Ubuntu 19.10, eoan!

After extract and run OTB (I just did in `/opt/`):

```
chmod +x OTB-7.0.0-Linux64.run
./OTB-7.0.0-Linux64.run
```

at this point you do not have all the environment variables settled, only the file that does the job (e.g. `..OTB-7.0.0-Linux64/otbenv.profile`). So, in order to import `otbApplication` under your Python application, you have to activate all the variable specified in `otbenv.profile`. First, check if all dependencies are ok:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-6 libxext6 libxau6 libxxf86vm1 libxdmcp6 libdrm2
```

activate the variables setting `otbenv.profile` in your `~/.profile`. So, open `~/.profile` and add `. /opt/OTB-7.0.0-Linux64/otbenv.profile`. Save and close. Finally, `source ~/.profile`.

If you still under virtualenv, just deactivate and activate again. To check if you properly import the environment variables, check the path printing `$PYTHONPATH`.

Last thing! If you run your code right now, you pretty much will get this message:

```
ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

which is [suggested](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/packages/nightly/latest/CookBook-6.7/Installation.html) to create a symlink of your python binding. So, first, find its location with:

```
find /usr/lib -iname *libpython3.*
```

copy the path outputs (something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so` -- in my case, using Python 3.7), and execute:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0
```

Now, I think you are OK to use library!

Answer (score 0):

I am Ubuntu 20.04 user, I had the same issue.

[Refer to Recompiling python binding section in orfeo documentation](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Installation.html)

- I have python 3.8 and OTB-7.4.0, so I had to recompile python binding and swig.
- As mentioned in Doc: If you are using another version of Python 3 than 3.5, but still want to use OTB Python bindings..

```
source otbenv.profile
ctest -S share/otb/swig/build_wrapping.cmake -VV
```

- During testing, make sure `echo $PYTHONPATH` points to correct path of `<OTB-App-folder>/lib/python`
- Now run python3 and try `import otbApplication`

Hope this helps!